# UrlMappings and Forms - how do they work?

Tags: forms, grails, url-mapping, urlmappings.groovy

UrlMappings are a great feature for links, but do they also work for forms?

Suppose we have a mapping like this:

```
"/map/$a" {
    controller="form"
    action="show"
}
```

a `<g:link controller="form" action="show" params="[a:'test'] />` will now be rewritten as
`<a href="/appname/map/test" />`

But a form like this:

```
<g:form controller="form" action="show">
   <g:textField name="a" />
</g:form>
```

will not have the same effect. It will result in requesting `/appname/form/show?a=whatever`

I know that a form can't be rewritten at HTML-creation time like a link - mainly because the value of the parameter is not known at this time, but I hoped that this URL would be redirected to the "nice" URL.

Is there a way to do stuff like that in grails? Or do I have to write my own redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I've found the answer:

URL-Rewriting seems only to work at the time when the HTML gets rendered. 
So

```
<g:form controller="form" action="show" params="[a:'test']">
   <g:textField name="b" />
</g:form>
```

will result in `/appname/map/test`. But that's not what I want - I want the URL to be rewritten when the form gets submitted.

So I came up with a redirect action:

```
class FormController {

    def index() { }
    def show() {
        render("yep"+params.a)
    }
    def submit() {
        redirect(controller:'form',action:'show',params:params)
    }
}
```

and I rewrite my form as

```
<g:form controller="form" action="submit">
   <g:textField name="a" />
</g:form>
```

This seems to work great (at the cost of one redirect)

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned, it can't be done at the time of page rendering due to unknown parameter values.  Plus you can imagine the problems that would ensue once you go beyond one form field.

You could either write some JavaScript to make a pretty URL in the onSubmit or if it's something you do all over the place you could probably make a custom tag.

Comment: the javascript is a great idea - it will solve my another problem, too! Thanx!